# C++ What is the behavior of a try-catch statement if an exception is thrown, and that exception does not match the type of exception caught?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I'm interested to know more about how the following code logic behaves:

```
try
{
    // might, or might not do this: throw ExceptionTypeA;
    function_which_might_throw_exception_type_a();
    
    do_A(); // do we do A?
}
catch(ExceptionTypeB)
{
    // B will never be done
    do_not_do_B();
}

// C is always done (Edit: should always be done, but actually isn't)
do_C();
```

In short, this question can simply be stated as: Will the function `do_A` be called?*

*[If `function_which_might_throw_exception_type_a()` does `throw ExceptionTypeA;`... It is of course clear that `do_A()` *will* be called if `function_which_might_throw_exception_type_a()` does not throw an exception.]

The pseduocode above is supposed to express throwing an exception of a type which is different to the type of exception caught in the `catch` clause.

In other words, while there is a `catch` clause, the exception will not be caught here, because it is not of the correct type.

In such cases, does the compiler produce an output which **skips the calling of `do_A()` entirely** or does the compiler produce an output in which **`do_A()` is called`**?

I am fairly confident that if any exception is thrown in the try block, then the execution path is to leave the try block immediately. **In other words, I think that `do_A()` is not called in the above pseudocode**. (Assuming that the function `function_which_might_throw_exception_type_a()` does throw `ExceptionTypeA`.)

However I wanted to check this, because I was starting to have doubts.

FYI: I am looking at a block of code which would more sensibly be written as:

```
try
{
    // might, or might not do this: throw ExceptionTypeA;
    function_which_might_throw_exception_type_a();
    
    do_A(); // do we do A?

    // C **should** always be done
    do_C()
}
catch(ExceptionTypeB)
{
    // B will never be done
    do_not_do_B();
}
return something;
```

however, I think that this would not be equivalent to the first pseudocode.

Since C++ does not have a try-catch-finally type statement, the logic cannot be expressed in this way. (But I think it would be better if it could have been.)

Comment: It appears that you're looking for the "catch-all handler" (`catch(...) {}`), as [described here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch).

Comment: @AdrianMole, no that won't work - but I can see why my pseduocode has caused this confusion... will update

Comment: @AdrianMole Is it clearer now?

Comment: `// C is always done` - It isn't. Throwing an exception unwinds the stack until a handler is found. There will be no `do_A`, no `do_C`, and possibly even a plain `std::terminate` if no handler for that exception exists.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica ... ah yes, I understand your point. I can see this question is an oversimplification of what I am looking at. But that does answer the question - thanks.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Just add that as an answer if you want, it's good enough for my purposes and confirms what I suspected was happening

Comment: @AdrianMole I think I now see what you were trying to point out: Yes, adding a catch all handler will solve the problem of `do_C()` *not* being called in the current logic. However I was thinking primarily about `do_A()`, hence my confusion with your comment.

Comment: Instead of using `catch`/`finally`, in C++ you can put any code that _must_ run at the end of a scope in a destructor. This guarantees that it will be called, no matter how the scope is left.

Comment: @user17732522 Valid point, however with the code I happen to be working on, I can't start making big changes such as wrapping things in class to do this. But granted, it is a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Will the function do_A be called?*

In short – no. When an exception is thrown inside a `try` block, that block will be exited *immediately*. If the type of exception thrown is not handled by a corresponding `catch` block, then it will be treated much like an exception thrown outside a `try` block would be (*possibly* causing a stack unwind but, ultimately, program termination).

If you want your `do_C()` function to be called 'always', whatever type of exception is thrown, then you should add a `catch(...)` (known as a "catch-all clause") block after your other, specific `catch` block(s). This can be an empty statement/block; if so, the thrown exception is still caught (i.e. is not propagated further) but no specific action is taken.

A possible way to implement what you appear to want is as follows:

```cpp
try
{
    // might, or might not do this: throw ExceptionTypeA;
    function_which_might_throw_exception_type_a();
    
    do_A(); // If the above throws, this WILL NOT be executed
}
catch(ExceptionTypeB)
{
    // B will never be done
    do_not_do_B();
}
catch(...) {} // This will catch "ExceptionTypeA" but do nothing about it ...
do_C();       // Will 'always' execute (unless an earlier catch re-throws)
return something;
```

Comment: In many situations you would probably want to execute `do_C` in the handler and then rethrow the exception. You can also guarantee that another rethrowing handler doesn't cause issues by using an additional `try`/`catch` pair. If no handler catches the exception it is unspecified whether any stack unwinding happens.